# service: command not found when trying to start vsftpd in centos

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, services, vsftpd

I am trying to use FTP on CentOS. I use this way to install:

```
sudo  yum -y install vsftpd
```

when I use `whereis` to check the location of vsftpd, I can find it:

[image]

But when I try

service vsftpd start

The error is:

> bash: service: command not found

I have tried all different ways to fix it. But none of them worked. Could anyone please help me here?

Comment: The error refers to the `service` command, not to the `vsftpd`. I believe that on CentOS, you need to use `systemctl`.

Comment: Yeah. thanks a lot. Could you please also tell me how to generate a new user and password. because when I use useradd, I get the error: bash: useradd: command not found

Comment: @FengChen that's because the correct command is `adduser`. To unlock the account, use `passwd` followed by the new user name you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the `service` command, not to the `vsftpd`.

On CentOS, you need to use `systemctl`.